# custom validation in django admin breaks datetime widget

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model that has a start and end date. 
The end date can be null and if the model is active it is treated as o
ongoing.

Each instance of the model has a field foo which is generated by a dynamic list. Foo is not unique across instances however two instances with the identical foo fields cannot be active at the same time.

The database I am using is PostgreSQL, and afaik this cannot be enforced at the database level. My choice was then to enforce this at the admin level. When adds a new instance of my model I wanted to validate that there were no conflicting instances at that point and raise a validation error. When I was going to test this locally the datetime widget is not displayed at all, only a textbox.

My question(s) are is this the best way to achieve what I want and if so why is the datetime widget missing and how can I get it back?

code snippet:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name',
                    'foo',
                    'active',
                    'created',
                    'started',
                    'ended']

    list_editable = ['name',
                     'active',
                     'ended']

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, *args, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name.lower() == 'foo':

            choices = sorted(some_dynamic_list)

            db_field.choices = choices

        return super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_changelist_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        parent_form = super().get_changelist_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.get_childform(parent_form)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, *args, **kwargs):
        parent_form = super().get_form(request, obj, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.get_childform(parent_form, obj)

    def get_childform(self, parent_form, obj=None):
        class ChildForm(parent_form):

            def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
                instance_dict = {}
                for instance in MyModel.objects.filter(active=True):
                    foo = instance.config_type.lower()
                    if foo in instance_dict:
                        instance_dict[foo].append(instance)
                    else:
                        instance_dict[foo] = [instance, ]
                if not obj:
                    for foo, instances in instance_dict.items():
                        for list_index, instance in enumerate(instances):
                            for other_instance in instances[list_index + 1:]:
                                if self.instances_conflict(instance, other_instance):
                                    raise forms.ValidationError("Instances of the same type must not overlap!")
                else:
                    for instance in instance_dict[obj.foo]:
                        if instance is not obj:
                            if self.instances_conflict(obj, instance):
                                raise forms.ValidationError("Instances of the same type must not overlap!")

                return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)

            def instances_conflict(self, instance_1, instance_2):
                if instance_1.ended is None and instance_2.started > instance_1.started:
                    return True

                if instance_2.ended is None and instance_1.started > instance_2.started:
                    return True

                if instance_1.started > instance_2.started and instance_1.started < instance_2.ended:
                    return True

                if instance_2.started > instance_1.started and instance_2.started < instance_1.ended:
                    return True

                return False
        return ChildForm
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: In the end I used a custom form for this and caught this situation during validation. The Constrains are something that I have not tried yet. I did however introduce a presave hook to raise an exception if this somehow made it past the model. In theory this means that someone can break this from the psql console. I will update further if I implement the constraints.

Comment: it will also break if .update() is called on a queryset because pre_save signal doesn't fire for that.

Answer (score 1):

**At the Database Level**

> The database I am using is PostgreSQL, and afaik this cannot be
>   enforced at the database level.

Well there are quite a few ways to do this at the database level with postgresql. [Constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-constraints.html) are what you should look at first. While databases like mysql are limited to Unique, Foreign Key and Primary Key constraints, postgresql can actually `CHECK` the values that are entered into the columns.

> A check constraint is the most generic constraint type. It allows you
>   to specify that the value in a certain column must satisfy a Boolean
>   (truth-value) expression.

You can create your constraint using a custom migration. But before that are you quite sure this is a situation that cannot be tackled by a together unique index on `active, foo` ?

The second thing that comes to mind is to create a BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE trigger to validate the data before it's written to the database.

The advantage of using a postgesql based approach is that if someone were to modify the data using PGAdmin the constraints would still be enforced.

**At the admin level.**

It would probably be a lot easier for you to override the save method in the django model or the [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method in the admin to check for constraints than your current approach.

> The save_model method is given the HttpRequest, a model instance, a
>   ModelForm instance and a boolean value based on whether it is adding
>   or changing the object. Here you can do any pre- or post-save
>   operations.